# Double gang box. One switched, three hot. Is a shared neutral OK?

Tags: electrical

I want to install a double gang box with one outlet switched and the other three always hot.
The way I was thinking of doing it was like this.

-Both neutrals would be connected as normal
-One of the receptacles hot side bridge would be clipped. 
-the hot feed connects to the bridged receptacle and one of the two on the "un-bridged" receptacle. 
-The feed is ran to a switch box and returned where it is wired to the final receptacle.

My experience with shard neutrals is less than good so I am wary about using them. This doesn't seem like it should cause a problem but I'm worried about getting feedback voltage from the neutral line.

Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've got it.

- Neutral feeder comes into the box, and pigtails out to each receptacle (silver colored screw) *and a neutral to the switch (if required by 2014 code)*.
- Hot feeder comes into the box, and pigtails to each receptacle (brass colored screw) and a hot to the switch.
- Switched hot comes into the box, and connects to one of the receptacle terminals.
- The bonding jumper on the receptacle with two hot feeds is broken.
- All grounding conductors are properly connected.

Comment: A switch feeding a receptacle does not require a neutral as per 404.2(C)(7).